# refactoring if else to Single line conditional statement in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to write single line if else check. But i am getting error.

Please help

```
if(x == 1) {
    System.out.println("aaa");
}else {
    System.out.println("bbb");
}
```

Is there a way to make above code as single like below. Getting compile error in below line

```
x == 1 ? System.out.println("aaa") : System.out.println("bbb");
```

Please help. I  might be making a silly error i guess.

Comment: Note: this is not "reformatting".  It is refactoring ... or rewriting.  Reformat implies that you are only concerned with the format of the code, and not its substance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second and third arguments of the conditional ternary expression must be expressions, so they can't be `System.out.println("aaa")`.

Instead, so you can write:

```
System.out.println (x == 1 ? "aaa" : "bbb");
```

Now you have a ternary conditional expression that produces a value (either "aaa" or "bbb"), and that value is passed to `System.out.println`.

Comment: Moreover, you can't use `?:` as an _expression statement_, even if the second and third operands are expressions, e.g. `someCondition ? 1 : 2;` is invalid: you have to do something with the value of the expression, e.g. `int a = someCondition ? 1 : 2;`.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator can only be used with expression returning a value. In your case, System.out.println("aaa") is not expression and can't be used.

You can use:

```
System.out.println(x == 1 ? "aaa" : "bbb");
```